# How to display additional information in Google Maps autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Google Places autocomplete to select cities by name. Currently it displays only the city name and the country it belongs to, in the suggestions drop down.

I have checked and found that the "address_components" object, that gets populated when a city is selected, has additional attibutes like state/province and other parts of the address. So, it is clear that the Google's API provide additional information other than merely the city and country names.

What I am trying to achieve is, displaying a couple of those additional data in the suggestions dropdown.

Is there a way to do that?

(I have marked on the screenshot where I need to display the additional attributes)[image]

Here is the code.

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete&query=locality" async defer></script>

 <script>
   var searchBox;
   function initAutocomplete() {

   var options = {types: ['(cities)']};

   var input = document.getElementById('placeAuto');
    searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
   searchBox.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
   }

  function fillInAddress()
  {
      var place = searchBox.getPlace();
      console.log(place);
  }

  </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Your screenshots represents the correct using of google autocomplete. Can you provide some code and explain in other words what do you want to accomplish? I want to help you

Comment: Please post your code. Show what you have tried. Explain what doesn't work and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Alex, Thanks. I have edited the question for make it more understandable.

Comment: So short answer: Yes. Good answer: I would not recommend doing that as you will need to make 1 place details query for each result, every single time the user enters or removes a letter from the autocomplete field, which, obviously can become a real issue depending on the usage of your tool. You could of course delay these queries for a few seconds which would cut the number of requests but will that be nice for the user?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I think that he asked how to display, not how to retrieve place details. It's possible to get those information, but it's not possible to insert them in the dropdown list of autocomplete, because it's customisation is limited. If it is, plaese provide some code to actually do this. It may help others.

Comment: Yes, that's what I commented below your answer. Not with the simple autocomplete, but with placesService, autocompleteService and `getQueryPredictions`. Ok I'll provide a proper answer since this seems to be of some interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented already, you can do that by using the Autocomplete and Places services and the `getPlacePredictions` method, but **I would not recommend this approach** as it will make a high number of requests to the API (one for each result, each time a user types something in the address field).

View the snippet in full screen mode as it won't fit hereunder or check it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/6c8hodw8/).

In this example I have added the place latitude and longitude in the autocomplete results.

```js
var autocompleteService, placesService, results, map;

function initialize() {

  results = document.getElementById('results');

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50, 50)
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  // Bind listener for address search
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('address'), 'input', function() {

    results.style.display = 'block';
    getPlacePredictions(document.getElementById('address').value);
  });

  // Show results when address field is focused (if not empty)
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('address'), 'focus', function() {

    if (document.getElementById('address').value !== '') {

      results.style.display = 'block';
      getPlacePredictions(document.getElementById('address').value);
    }
  });

  // Hide results when click occurs out of the results and inputs
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document, 'click', function(e) {

    if ((e.target.parentElement.className !== 'pac-container') && (e.target.parentElement.className !== 'pac-item') && (e.target.tagName !== 'INPUT')) {

      results.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });

  autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
}

// Get place predictions
function getPlacePredictions(search) {

  autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions({
    input: search,
    types: ['geocode']
  }, callback);
}

// Place search callback
function callback(predictions, status) {

  // Empty results container
  results.innerHTML = '';

  // Place service status error
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    results.innerHTML = '<div class="pac-item pac-item-error">Your search returned no result. Status: ' + status + '</div>';
    return;
  }

  // Build output for each prediction
  for (var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++) {

    // Get place details to inject more details in autocomplete results
    placesService.getDetails({
      placeId: prediction.place_id
    }, function(place, serviceStatus) {

      if (serviceStatus === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        // Create a new result element
        var div = document.createElement('div');

        // Insert inner HTML
        div.innerHTML += '<span class="pac-icon pac-icon-marker"></span>' + place.adr_address + '<div class="pac-item-details">Lat: ' + place.geometry.location.lat().toFixed(3) + ', Lng: ' + place.geometry.location.lng().toFixed(3) + '</div>';

        div.className = 'pac-item';

        // Bind a click event
        div.onclick = function() {

          var center = place.geometry.location;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: center,
            map: map
          });

          map.setCenter(center);
        }

        // Append new element to results
        results.appendChild(div);
      }
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

table td {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #777;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.pac-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 350px;
}

.pac-icon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/autocomplete-icons.png);
  background-size: 34px;
}

.pac-icon-marker {
  background-position: -1px -161px;
}

.pac-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 4px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  color: #999;
}

.pac-item:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.pac-item-details {
  color: lightblue;
  padding-left: 22px;
}

.pac-item-error,
.pac-item-error:hover {
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="address">Address:</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="address" placeholder="Enter address" type="text" tabindex="1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div id="results" class="pac-container"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```